# Home directory mounted read only file system

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount

I'm using Ubuntu server 9.04

My home directory mounded Read only filesystem

```
$ ls
Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop  README.txt

$ cat README.txt
THIS DIRECTORY HAS BEEN UNMOUNTED TO PROTECT YOUR DATA.

From the graphical desktop, click on:
 "Access Your Private Data"

or

From the command line, run:
 $ ecryptfs-mount-private
```

How to recover?

I tried it

```
$ ecryptfs-mount-private
Enter your login passphrase:

Warning: Using default salt value (undefined in ~/.ecryptfsrc)
Error: Unwrapping passphrase and inserting into the user session keyring failed [1]
Info: Check the system log for more information from libecryptfs
ERROR: Your passphrase is incorrect
```

Answer (score 1):

From the command line, run:

```
$ ecryptfs-mount-private
```

or click on "Access Your Private Data" on the graphical desktop.

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried it , but I can't recover

Answer (score 0):

As it says, check what's in the logfile

```
Info: Check the system log for more information from libecryptfs
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!. How to check he system log for more information from libecryptfs, sorry I'm beginner for linux